# I need to break a url into different sets of characters and have only specific sets show in a textbox

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want to copy a URL into textbox1, click button1 or button2, and only have part of the url show in textbox2.  The problem is, the URL will always have a different amount of characters in it.  However, the URLs will always have two sets of characters in it. ("&key=" and "%9D") Lets say this is the URL:

http://apps.beta.com/station/track.php?range=&cat=examination&subcat=toe**&key=**a03e7de9a8d0b9d$$ceK2U_XZ*0bNY5*UFXT,,1Ni9_hLIuYmoarj(5-08kwE33x&next=view.php%3FfrHost%3D1256799722%26frId%3Dcv5wgk88og8gkggw%9D6frType%3DToeSize%26key%3Da03e7d0b9d%24%24ceK2U_XZ%9DA0bNY5%2ADT%2F2C1NiN_hLIarj%9D85-08kwE33x**%9D**234f234hj5k332.png

I've marked the two sections in bold text that I need to worry about.  If I press button1 I need everything before "&key=" to show in textbox1 (the URL will only have 1 set of characters that say &key=).  If I press button2 I need everything after the last "%9D" to show in textbox2 (the url will have "%9D" in multiple location throughout).

I thought this would be a simple project to build, but because the number of characters are never the same in each url, I'm having trouble displaying what I want.  Any ideas How I can write this out?

Thanks for any help you guys  can offer!

**[Edit]**
The closest I've come to solving the problem is this:

`Public Class Form1`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strResults As String
    strResults = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox2.Text = strResults.Substring(0, 72)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim strResults As String
    strResults = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox2.Text = strResults.Substring(strResults.Length - 18)
End Sub
```

`End Class`

But this only works on exact numbers...  They number of characters before "&key="  and after "%9D"  will usually be different with each URL.  So, I'm not sure how to change this to suit my needs.

Comment: You need to do this on the server side or the client side? Also, what languague(s) and technolog(y|ies) are you using?

Comment: I need to do this client side and I'm using VB with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I'm not sure jball.  I'm just trying to add a feature to a Windows forms application. It's .Net framework 3.0 if that helps.  Basically, I've created an application for updating a database on the web.  But I'm doing everything in a Windows forms application.  Even the browser open up on the form.  I can copy/past the URLs to a textbox and highlight the part I don't want, remove it, then copy/past the parts I want in the appropriate fields.  But, we're sifting through a lot of URLs and I'm looking for a faster way to brake down them down accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN forums were helpful in answering the question and pointing me in the right direction:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("&key="))
    TextBox3.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf("%9D") + 1)

  End Sub
```

I made a few changes to handle errors in case the characters weren't in the url.
But, the above code was the solution to the question I asked here.  I'm posting the solution here in case someone in the future has a similar question.